# C# Scaling Axes of chart

Tags: c#, charts, axis

I have a problem with charts in my application. I want to use charts to display histograms of pictures. I want to add a gradient rectangle under chart with colors from black to R/G/B/White, so I draw it as Background Image of each chart. When values on AxisY ar greater then 1k everything is fine, but when those values have less then 4 digits there is a problem [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUt5h.png). Anyone know how to prevent extension of AxisX?
[image]

Init charts:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            ca = new ChartArea();
            ca.AxisX.Interval = 1D;
            ca.AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
            ca.AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.LabelAutoFitStyles.WordWrap;
            ca.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            ca.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
            ca.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            ca.BackSecondaryColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            ca.BorderWidth = 0;
            ca.Name = "ChartArea" + i.ToString();
            ca.AxisY.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.DecreaseFont;
            ca.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
            ca.AxisX.Interval = 256;
            ca.AxisY.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;

            s = new Series();
            s.BorderWidth = 0;
            s.ChartArea = "ChartArea" + i.ToString();
            s.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
            s.Name = "Series" + i.ToString(); ;
            s.Color = Colors[i];
            s["PointWidth"] = "1";

            HistCharts[i] = new Chart();
            HistCharts[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right;
            HistCharts[i].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            HistCharts[i].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.None;
            HistCharts[i].BorderlineWidth = 0;
            HistCharts[i].ChartAreas.Add(ca);
            HistCharts[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(405, (i + 3) * Form.Height / 6 - 28);
            HistCharts[i].Name = "Chart" + i.ToString();
            HistCharts[i].Series.Add(s);
            HistCharts[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(297, Form.Height / 6 - 27);
            HistCharts[i].TabIndex = 6;
            HistCharts[i].Text = "chart" + i.ToString();
            HistCharts[i].Visible = false;
            HistCharts[i].SendToBack();
        }

        SetChartImage();
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            HistCharts[i].BackgroundImage = HistImages[i];
```

Set new series and paint:

```
        if(Hists == null)
            {
                HistCharts[0].Visible = false;
                HistCharts[1].Visible = false;
                HistCharts[2].Visible = false;
                UpdateStatTimer(Time);
                return;
            }

            HistCharts[0].BackgroundImage = HistImages[Hists.Length > 1 ? 1 : 0];

            if(Hists[0].SequenceEqual(Hists[1]) && Hists[0].SequenceEqual(Hists[2]))
            {
                HistCharts[0].Series[0].Color = Color.Black;
                HistCharts[0].BackgroundImage = HistImages[0];
                HistCharts[0].Visible = true;
                HistCharts[1].Visible = false;
                HistCharts[2].Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                HistCharts[0].Series[0].Color = Color.Red;
                HistCharts[0].BackgroundImage = HistImages[1];
                HistCharts[0].Visible = true;
                HistCharts[1].Visible = true;
                HistCharts[2].Visible = true;
            }

            int Max = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                HistCharts[i].Series[0].Points.Clear();
                HistCharts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = Double.NaN;
                for(int j = 0; j < Hists[i].Length; j++)
                    HistCharts[i].Series[0].Points.AddXY(j + 0.5, Hists[i][j]);
                HistCharts[i].Update();
                if(HistCharts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum > Max)
                    Max = (int) HistCharts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum;
            }
            if(StatisticsItemCheck.Checked == false)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    HistCharts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = Max;
            }
```

if all Hists are equal Green and Blue histograms are invisible and Red Histogram becomes GrayScale Histogram

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should be including relevant code with your questions if you want help faster. We're coders around here and there's not a lot we can do for you without any code. As it stands I can recommend some photoshopping that might fix that picture you included.

Comment: I have to agree with leigero: We need to see at least the paint code. I assume all images and all chartareas have the same size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really about **scaling**..:

The reason your images don't always align with the Y-Axis is that the Y-Axis legend takes more or less room in various cases. This make the [inner plot area](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.innerplotposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) move to the right and your carefully aligned image doesn't fit anymore.

When the Y-Axis moves to the right the whole plotarea shrinks, at least if the default vlaues of `Auto` are still valid for the various elements..

The simplest workaround is to set the position from `Auto` to a fixed value that suits all your data:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.X = someValue;
```

Note that all [element position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.elementposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) values are in percent of the whole chart! So maybe you will want to modify it upon resizing the chart..? As you have noticed, you also have to resize you images..

To find a good value you can use the debugger to see which are the current ones in both of your cases and pick the larger one and then some extra for safety..

In the same veign you **may** want to get better control over the format, i.e. the number of digits on your y-axis label values, maybe like this..:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "0.00"; // some formatstring
```

Update:

To make use of the system's `AutoScaling` during(after a resize, you can use this workaround:

First set the `Auto` on and copy the resulting `Elementposition`. Then use those values to create a new one under control:

```
int LeftEdge = yourValue;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.Auto = true;
ElementPosition EP = chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition =  
                     new ElementPosition(LeftEdge, EP.Y, EP.Height, 100 - LeftEdge);
```

Comment: When chart is resized I resize also this backGround Bitmp. Chart can only be resized verticaly. Your answer fixes some problems, but how to make Height autoscale with fixed X position?

Comment: Can you explain this a little more?

Comment: I want to make this plot's X position and width constant. But when I resize form I would like the plot to be higher. So when I set InnerPlotPosition.X with someValue its Y position and height stop beiing auto.

Comment: Ah! See my update for a workaround to use with the resizing!